# unity: how can I paste an arial photograph on a terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geography

I produced a hightmap from a digital land model and placed it as a terrain into unity. How can I put an arial photograph on it?
Any hints are welcome!
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the terrain splatmap, in Unity i think it is called alphamap.

Doc available here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.html

Please note that one splatmap can only store 4 textures, so if your arial photograph contains more then 4 different texture types you will need to think in arrays of splatmaps.

If this method does not fit your needs then you need a projector or decal method, read about them.

Alternative way:
If you dont need any runtime magic, you can just add a texture, to your terrain, this texture will be your arial map, and basically fit this onto your terrain. But one texture on large terrains would produce quite bad results imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating a mesh procedurally, and setting the UVs according to the size of the image file.

Look up "procedural mesh UV unity"